# Declaring window property in javascript with value undefined

Tags: javascript

I was trying to declare a window property when I came across this problem.
What is the difference between the following two code snippets?

```
<script>
    window.prop=undefined;
    alert(window.prop);//undefined
    alert(prop);//undefined
</script>
```

And

```
<script>
    window.prop;
    alert(window.prop);//undefined
    alert(prop);//ReferenceError: prop is not defined
</script>
```

As per my understanding they are doing the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `window.prop=undefined;`, you actually declare the variable on the window object.

`window.prop;` just returns the value.

Example:

```
a = {};
a.prop = undefined;
console.log(a); // Object {prop: undefined}
```

```
a = {};
a.prop;
console.log(a); // Object {}
```

In the first example, `prop` actually exists on `a` (or `window`, in your case), meaning it can be logged.
In the second example, it doesn't exist. When accessing normal objects, `a.prop` just returns `undefined`. However, when the object is `window`, it throws a reference error when accessing undefined variables on `window`.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, `window.prop` is defined and the value `undefined` is assigned to it.

However, in the second example, the `window.prop` property is `undefined`, which means that it doesn't really exist, and then JavaScript throws a `ReferenceError`.

[This article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) on MDN describes `undefined` value in JavaScript.

Comment: so undefined is a value given to a variable which states that the variable does not really exist?

Comment: @vartia, undefined is the state of a reference, if you like, that has been defined (the reference has been defined/setup) but who's value has not been assigned (maybe that makes sense/helps?)

Comment: No. `undefined` is a value. The point is that, if you assign it to a property of any object, this property turns to exist with the value `undefined`. However, if the property doesn't exist, then when you try to access this property it also returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

The first line of the second script block actually evaluates `window.prop` returning it's value (or in this case that it is `undefined`)